# 2.83: Snapping to edge not working correctly

Tags: snapping

[image]

In the above image, these two planes are same mesh. I want to stick both with snap to edge at the red line in the below image.

[image]

However, when I tried to choose the vertical one in edit mode and put G key to do that, it failed like the below image.

[image]

So, will someone teach me how to snap correctly? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the setting properlly?

[image]

It will snap to edge, all length of edge. It shouldn't align it for you since not all edge are in same length

So Snap it to the corner

[image]

And if you give additional axis constraints, (eg. lock to x-y plane), it might be more buggy to align on. Not sure it's intentionally designed or just a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My setting was wrong, solved the problem. Thank you!